# JOIN using sqlx causes 'missing destination name'

Tags: go, sqlx

I have this query that works fine on mysql and return the intended result, but [sqlx](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx) has difficulty to handle it:

```
var jokes []model.Joke
err := shared.Dbmap.Select(&jokes, "SELECT * FROM joke INNER JOIN jokevote ON joke.id=jokevote.joke_id AND jokevote.vote=? AND joke.user_id=?", 1, userId)
if err != nil {
    log.Println(err)
}
```

At runtime, I get no result but this error message in terminal:

> missing destination name joke_id

I don't have this issue when querying a single table.

So I'm wondering what is wrong here and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:** Here are the structs:

```
type Joke struct {
    ID         int       `db:"id" json:"id"`
    UserID     int       `db:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
    Title      string    `db:"title" json:"title"`
    Content    string    `db:"content" json:"content"`

...
}

type JokeVote struct {
    ID     int `db:"id" json:"id"`
    JokeID int `db:"joke_id" json:"joke_id"`
    UserID int `db:"user_id" json:"user_id"`
    Vote   int `db:"vote" json:"vote"`
}
```

Comment: Does your `model.Joke` include a field with a `db:"joke_id"` annotation ?

Comment: No. it has only `db:"id"` for the primary key. Just added the structs.

Comment: Then sqlx doesn't know on which member of `model.Joke` to Scan `joke_id`. You can either add a `JokeID` field to `model.Joke` (with the appropriate `db` annotation), or specify the columns you want to get back manually in your query (instead of the `SELECT *`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you execute "SELECT * FROM joke INNER JOIN jokevote" you will get columns from both joke and jokevote tables. 
Try to query "SELECT joke.* FROM joke INNER JOIN jokevote" to get only columns from joke table.

Comment: Yes, this `SELECT joke.* FROM joke ...` solved the problem. Thanks!